# Under what conditions do the phase margin and Nyquist criteria give the same results?

Tags: linear-systems, control-systems, nyquist, stability, minimum-phase

When designing feedback systems, I often evaluate stability by thinking about phase margin: the closed loop system $$T(s) = \frac{L(s)}{1+L(s)}$$ is stable if $L(s)$ has positive phase margin, i.e., 
$$\angle L(j\omega) > -\pi/2$$ at all frequencies for which $$|L(j\omega)|>1$$. This is easy to visualize graphically using a Bode plot.

But for some systems -- typically involving right-half-plane poles and/or zeros in $L(s)$ -- this criterion doesn't work and we need to use the Nyquist criterion to check stability. That is, the number of unstable closed-loop poles is equal to the number of encirclements of $-1+j0$ by the polar plot of $L(s)$ when $s$ is evaluated along an appropriate contour. My understanding is that this Nyquist criterion is more general, and the "positive phase margin" rule is a simplification that only applies in certain cases.

I'm looking for a criterion that will let me decide when these two criteria (positive phase margin and the Nyquist test) will give me the same results. I suspect that it involves right-half-plane poles and/or zeros in $L(s)$, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out, the nyquist stability criterion is more general, moreover, is the **only** stability criterion. Nevertheless, the Bode plot give us the exact same information that the nyquist plot does, so the stability of a system can be determined with either the bode or the nyquist plot, some times its easier with the former and other times with the latter. for **minimum phase** system this is usually easier with the bode plot, since you only have to see that (as you said) $$\angle L(j\omega) > -\pi/2 $$
at all frequencies for which
$$|L(j\omega)| > 1 $$

Answering your question explicitly, this is only valid for **minimum phase** systems. For systems that are not minimun phase the gain and phase margins are not as straightfoward to find.